# Base resistance missing in BC817-40 datasheet

Tags: bjt, noise, datasheet

I need to calculate noise at the base of my BJT so I need base resistance for that, but I could not find this parameter in any datasheet. How do I can calculate noise then? Do I have to measure base resistance on my own? If so, how? I am using sot23-5 BC817-40.

Comment: If you're that concerned about noise, why are you using a general-purpose bjt instead of a low-noise bjt or a jfet?

Comment: Well, it's a long story . I need to calculate it for this one.

Comment: Do you want to measure the rbb' (base spreading resistance)?

Comment: Yes, the resistance of the base material.

Comment: My 2 cents: you're not going to get an answer here. The BC817 is a transistor used for switching things on/off so base resistance is irrelevant. Noise is irrelevant as well. If you "must" then use a transistor with a more detailed specification. Sure you can try to measure the base resistance but that will be a challenge if you do not have experience with that kind of thing. How to guarantee that you're **only** measuring the base resistance? You might need specialist equipment as well.

Comment: If a parameter, such as base resistance, isn't specified in a data sheet it is because the manufacturer doesn't guarantee maintaining a consistent value for the parameter. It probably also isn't a 'good' value, whatever good means for that parameter. If a parameter is important to you it's best to use a device where the manufacturer actually specifies that parameter in the data sheet. As you're stuck using a device without a specification you may have to not only measure the base resistance on the device you have but also on every device you use as the value may not be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

The real issue here is that you are worrying about noise in a BC817 (aka BC337 in SOT23). They are called *general purpose amplifiers* but they are really meant as switching transistors. They even give the thermal transient curve for that.

Probably it's not there because either a) it's not something to write home about or b) it's not a process controlled spec so it could be anything at the end of the day.

Comment: I found here saying it's value about 30 ohms : http://www.janascard.cz/PDF/Design%20of%20ultra%20low%20noise%20amplifiers.pdf